# Como fazer video 360º

Tags: javascript

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer um video panoramico que gira 360 graus? Onde clica e navega pelo video 360 graus

Comment: emersonnw, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Sua pergunta foi fechada porque vários usuários consideraram-na [vaga](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Isso significa que não é possível responder objetivamente. No entanto você pode editá-la de acordo com o formato do site, por exemplo, especificando melhor o que quer e focando em uma dúvida técnica ao invés de simplesmente pedir tudo pronto. Sugiro que leia sobre [como fazer uma boa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Fique à vontade também para fazer outras perguntas, apenas procure seguir o formato do site. Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Tente o Valiant 360º.

Está disponivel no GitHub.

https://github.com/flimshaw/Valiant360

Comment: Fantástica biblioteca, nota mil, valeu!